# Role Provider In ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, roleprovider, role

I have these roles:Admin, Doctor and Patient. But login information is stored in different table. Admin's username and password are stored in User_TABle(They are two items). Patient's Login information is stored in Patient_TABLE: PatientID, Year and DocumentID(They are three items). I want to use SQLRoleProvider and SQLProfileProvider. How can I design different login page with loginView?

Sincerely yours

Comment: If you are looking at using a custom membership Schema (i.e. the one you defined in the question) then you are likely going to run into issues with most of the login/membership controls. Have you defined a custom MembershipProvider using the defined schema?

Comment: when I use roleprovider, I use the `MembershipProvider` at the same time, so all users login info saved in one table. I just guess, if you changed the course, you have to finish with your own.

Comment: @EricYin - I think you mean MembershipProvider not MembershipService

Comment: @PaulSullivan, you right. I wrapped it, so I forget it's real name. Changed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a better setup would be this:

Use the standard MembershipProvider shipped with ASP.NET to use in conjunction with RoleProvider. Once this is setup and you have the roles you can store personal information for each either by:

Using ProfileProvider (not a bad method but requires a bit of work as you have polymorphic data (you would store it using XML in text field of the provider or write your own custom profile provider)

OR

Add a table similar to your schema but with a foreign key to the aspnet_Users PK. In code then you could do Roles.IsUserInRole("Whatever") and change the loginView appropriately. It would also mean you could just drag and drop the remaining LoginControl etc and have it just work with the standard membership provider

Comment: I do not know the userRole because he is not login yet. I have a problem in loginView. I have different userType. Should I design different loginView for them?

Comment: How can you design a different loginview if you do not know who the user is - by definition they must be logged in before you can show anything meaningful to the usertype.

Answer (score 0):

**SqlRoleProvider**, **SqlProfileProvider** and **SqlMembershipProvider** come with default Aspnetdb.

To create the database used by these providers, run the aspnet_regsql.exe executable found in the C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\ versionNumber folder. Otherwise, you have to create **CustomRoleProvider**, **CustomProfileProvider** and **CustomMembershipProvider**.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.sqlroleprovider.aspx

Comment: You dont even have to doo this anymore within VS2010 - create new ASP.NET project and just try login from the default site with dummy credentials. Just this act invokes the database and schema creation

Comment: Does Multiple UserType Solved with CustomRoleProvider? If yes how can I do that?
I used CustomProvider for one userType.